# Do recent motherboards come with a speaker for POST beeps?

Tags: motherboard

I've seen many questions of computers not starting and people here recommending to buy a motherboard speaker.

Isn't the motherboard speaker already included in a motherboard? I never had to buy one and my current motherboard has this speaker, that's why I'm wondering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the motherboard. Not all of them ship with a speaker, but all of them have a header for one.

Comment: Is there any criteria for not having one? Or it depends how cheap/expensive the mb is?

Comment: I'm not sure what it depends on. Hopefully most manufacturers specify it on the box if it is included.

Comment: Good. Thanks for clarifying :)